# solving non-homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

solve the equation $a_n − 4a_{n−2} = −3n + 8$
for initial values $a_0=2, a_1=1$

I'm stuck on finding the particular solution for $a_n$. I tried using the form $a_n = C_1n + C_2$ but that gets me nowhere??

Comment: It works, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are easily found. They are $1$ and $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, rewrite the recurrence so there aren't subtractions in indices:

$$
a_{n + 2} - 4 a_n = - 3 n + 2
$$

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize some sums:

$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} - 4 A(z)
  = - 3 \sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n + 2 \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$

Note that:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n
  &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \\
  &= \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align}$

Plug this into the above with the initial values, and solve for $A(z)$:

$\begin{align}
A(z)
  &= \frac{2 - 3 z + 2 z^2 - 4 z^3}{(1 - z)^2 (1 - 2 z) (1 + 2 z)} \\
  &= \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
       - \frac{1}{1 - z}
       + \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
       + \frac{1}{1 + 2 z}
\end{align}$

Read off the coefficient for $z^n$, knowing that:

$$
(1 - z)^{-r}
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-r}{n} z^n
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1} z^n
$$

so:

$\begin{align}
a_n
  &= [z^n] A(z) \\
  &= (n + 1) - 1 + 2^n + (-2)^n \\
  &= n + 2^n + (-2)^n
\end{align}$